# VBA codes developed in Excel 2003

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2003

I just need to ask to what degree Macros developed in Excel 2003 are compatible with Excel 2010 and 2013?

I would tend to think that there would be some issues, but from your experience, what percentage of macros developed in Excel 2003 can work in Excel 2010/2013?

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are going to have is with 32/64 bit compatibility.  Office 2003 is 32-bit only; starting with Office 2007, some versions are 64-bit.

Microsoft has a pretty good writeup of the issues on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee691831%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You should do some online searches for **VBA** features that were "deprecated" after Excel 2003.  The single major feature that no longer works is **Application.FileSearch**

Answer (score 0):

Just from **msdn.microsoft.com**:

- [Excel 2010 Object Model Changes Since Earlier Versions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee836187%28v=office.14%29.aspx)
- [What's New in Excel 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837594%28v=office.14%29.aspx)
- [New Objects, Collections, and Enumerations_Excel.Dev](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197990%28v=office.14%29.aspx)
- [New Members and Constants_Excel.Dev](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194938%28v=office.14%29.aspx)
- [Tables of VBA Object Model Changes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms474284%28v=office.14%29.aspx)
- [VBA Object Model Changes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff512734%28v=office.14%29.aspx)
- [Word 2010 Object Model Changes Since Earlier Versions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee836186%28v=office.14%29.aspx)
- [What's new for VBA developers in Project 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj651153.aspx?query=What%27s+new+for+VBA+developers)
- And so on ...